Docker Install in Linux Mint
I am learning Docker.
How to install Docker in Linux Mint 21.3?

You can install Docker on Linux Mint by running
sudo apt install docker.io


You can install docker-ce on Linux Mint. Linux Mint Virginia is based on Ubuntu 22.04. We use the official docker documentation by replacing virginia codename by jammy.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce

